# Why can't my ASP.NET Core 2 method return TwiML?

Tags: c#, twilio, asp.net-core-2.0, twilio-twiml

I have an ASP.NET Core 2 application and I'm trying to forward a call made to a Twilio number to another number. When I try to return `TwiML` I get an error that says:

> "Non-invocable member 'TwiML' cannot be used like a method."

Here's the method:

```
[HttpPost]
public TwiMLResult ForwardCall(string called)
{
   var response = new VoiceResponse();
   response.Dial(newNumber);

   return TwiML(response);
}
```

The error happens here:

```
return TwiML(response);
```

All the code examples I've seen tell me to return the `TwiML` this way but for some reason, I'm unable to.

Comment: Haven't worked with Twilio's C# SDK, so taking a guess. Is it possible to that TwiML is a class and so you should do `return new TwiML(response);` ? Also, shouldn't that API be `HttpGet` ?

Comment: What is `TwiML`? Where is it defined? The error says that it's *not* a function so you can't call it like that

Comment: The [documentation example](https://www.twilio.com/docs/guides/creating-aspnet-mvc-webhook-project?code-sample=code-aspnet-mvc-webhook-example&code-language=cs&code-sdk-version=default) shows that `TwiML` is a member of `TwillioController` and your controller has to inherit from it. Where does your controlelr inherit from? Please post enough code that people can reproduce your issue

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, you nailed it! I needed my controller to inherit from TwilioController. Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The problem was that the controller was not inheriting from TwilioController. Once I had my controller inherit from TwilioController the error went away.

Answer (score 0):

Since `TwiML` is just `XML`, I would consider returning a `ContentResult` instead.

The `ContentResult` object is an `ActionResult` that returns a simple string. It also supports setting the `Content-Type` that will be returned with the response:

```
[HttpPost]
public ContentResult ForwardCall(string called)
{
   var response = new VoiceResponse();
   response.Dial(newNumber);

   return new ContentResult(TwiML(response), "text/xml");
}
```

Comment: That's not what the question is about. The OP couldn't even call the `TwiML` function

Answer (score 0):

If you are having this problem from an Azure Function, and you cant inherit from the TwilioController, something like this will work, after all TwiML is just XML.

```
[FunctionName("ProcessCall")]
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
    ILogger log)
{
    var voiceResponse = new VoiceResponse();

    voiceResponse.Dial(number: "<NumberGoesHere>");

    return new HttpResponseMessage
    {
        Content = new StringContent(voiceResponse.ToString(), System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/xml")
    };
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Probably more .net nuget related, but I had to uninstall/re-install twilio package before visual studio recognized the Twilio.Aspnet namespace.